# Why don't browser cache common JS files?

Tags: browser, javascript, browser-cache

One of the big tradeoffs in web development is on reducing the total size of your JS files to maintain page load times low.
My reasonable guess is that most websites include a similar subset of JS files. Think about jQuery, YUI and other widely used libraries.
Is there a reason for browsers not to have common libraries stored locally and save an unnecessary request and download time?

Comment: That's why, for example, developers can include jQuery from CDNs such as [Google's libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).

Comment: unless your JS files are *huge*, load times are insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

Because they have no way of knowing that `http://somerandomsite.com/js/jquery.js` is, in fact, the same version of jQuery that the browser has – or even jQuery at all.

Comment: An easy solution to this issue is allowing websites to "subscribe" to the feature and let the browser assume that it is pointing to the correct jQuery version.